# Open and edit HUGE file

Tags: search, editor, syntax-highlighting, edit

What is a good editor to view and edit huge files (~4 gb) quickly? Customizable syntax highlighting and a search feature are preffered, but not required.

Answer (score 1):

I've had decent success with [vim](http://www.vim.org).

Comment: +1 For an editor that not only handles large files, but is also 8-bit clean and runs without a gui.

Answer (score 0):

TextPad - http://www.textpad.com/

Answer (score 0):

Liquid Studio Community Edition contains a [Large File Editor](https://www.liquid-technologies.com/large-file-editor) which can open and edit Terra-byte files on low spec machines, and its free.

[image: Liquid Studio Large File Editor]